# Shared teams for multiple projects in VSTS

Tags: azure-devops

I'm wondering if anyone has any good practices for teams shared across multiple projects in VSTS.

We have about a dozen projects with different teams (web, app etc). However, the marketing team is completing design and UI tasks for all projects. Our main problem is that the marketing team is cluttered with a lot of projects without any form of an overview.

Is there a way for a "shared" team to work effectively with tasks and user stories from multiple projects?

Comment: When you say "projects", are you referring to Team Projects, which are a specific entity in VSTS, or are you talking about something else?

Comment: I am referring to team projects yes. We have created one team project per real-life project (per customer basically). I am still learning this thing so just so im getting this right. We have multiple teams within each Project (the ones showing up on the front page under "all projects"), however some of these teams are working on multiple customer-projects (with their own team project)

Answer (score 0):

For now, there has no such backlog or kanban board to show all the work items accross projects.

And there has an user voice [Allow Teams to work over multiple Projects (Teams at the Collection level in Visual Studio Online),](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/7695204-allow-teams-to-work-over-multiple-projects-teams) which suggests this feature, you can vote and follow up.

The workaround for now is you can ask the marketing team to **get related work items across projects by query**.
Detail as below:

Create a query -> select Query across projects options -> add criteria to specify the projects you want to get related work items -> add other criteria you need -> Run query.

[image]

Then the related work items accross projects will be listed.